# how does .isalpha and elif works ? (python)

Tags: python, edx

I want to create a code that prints words in uppercase (after "G") from a sentence

```
# [] create words after "G"
# sample quote "Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart" ~ Confucius (551 BC - 479 BC)

# Sample output:

WHERESOEVER
YOU
WITH
YOUR
HEART
```

here is my code

```
q = input ("Quote : ")

word = ""
for a in q :
    if a.isalpha() == True :
        word = word + a
    elif word[0].lower() > "g" :
        print (word.upper())
        word = ""
    else :
        word = ""
```

it runs well until the last word of the sentence, it can't print the words although the first letter is after "G". Also, when it found punctuation, it stuck, and says

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-29b3e8e00230> in <module>()
      8     if a.isalpha() == True :
      9         word = word + a
---> 10     elif word[0].lower() > "g" :
     11         print (word.upper())
     12         word = ""

IndexError: string index out of range
```

I'm suspicious it has something whether with the `.isalpha` or the `elif`

I need to know how to fix it and where do I made mistakes

Comment: What is the idea behind `elif ord(word[0].lower()) > 103`? Why do you print when this condition matches?

Comment: That bit would be a lot clearer if it said `elif word[0].lower() > 'g'` rather than have the magic number 103 with no explanation in your code.

Comment: If you get an exception from this code (and I did when I ran it), please include the details of the exception in your question.

Comment: thanks, I have edited my code. I didn't know I can do that. By exception, do you mean the kind of error I encountered? IndexError: string index out of range. I'm sorry, I just started coding

Comment: An exception normally produces a stack trace, which is a message describing an error, and a list of lines that tell you where the error occurred. You should include the stack trace in your question, or even better, use it to figure out where the problem is in your code.

Comment: I've edited my question. It says the string index is out of range, I don't understand how index 0 can be out of range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two characters in succession that are not letters (such as a comma followed by a space), then you will hit `elif word[0].lower() > "g"` when `word` is the empty string, so there will be no character at `word[0]`. That is what causes the exception.

Simplistically, you could avoid this by checking `word` isn't empty before you try and get `word[0]`.

```
elif word and word[0].lower() > "g":
```

That at least should avoid the exception.

---

> But I still have the last word issue, it doesn't print the last word although it started with alphabet greater than "G"

You only print when you hit a non-alphabetic character. So if you pass a word and then don't hit a non-alphabetic character, then the last word will not be printed.

To solve that, you can add a `print` after the end of your loop, in case there is a final word still to be printed.

```
for a in q:
    ... etc.

if word and word[0].lower() > 'g':
    print(word)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.   But I still have the last word issue, it doesn't print the last word although it started with alphabet greater than "G"

Comment: OK. I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will encounter two problems

1) Accessing `word[0]` while it is an empty string.
      Will give an error when you have successive non-alphabets.
 2) Word is only printed when `isalpha()` is false.
      Here that simply means last word, "HEART" wont be printed.

To solve (1) you can check if word is an empty string before `elif word[0].lower() > "g" :` by adding `if word==""`. If it is an empty string we can skip the iteration, tackling the problem (1). To skip, you can use `continue` statement.[What's continue?](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/continue.html)  [Detailed explanation here.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_continue_statement.htm) Or just `word = ""`

To solve (2) you can do a simple trick by adding a whitespace after quote `q+=" "` {shortcut for`q=q+""`thus ensuring a non-alphabet as last character. Do it right after inputting quote.Or you can add

```
if word[0].lower() > "g" :
    print (word.upper())
```

to the end.
Now, my suggested final code will be,

```
q = input ("Quote : ")
q+=" "
word = ""
for a in q :
    if a.isalpha() == True :
        word += a
    elif word =="":
        continue
    elif word[0].lower() > "g" :
        print (word.upper())
        word = ""
    else :
        word = ""
```